# PHP associative array to JSON using json_encode

Tags: php, json, associative-array

I need to convert `tempArr`, an associative array, to JSON and write it in a file.

I am using the following code, but I get a *json_encode(): recursion detected* warning.

```php
$tempArr = array('one' => $var1, 'two'=> $var2, 'three'=>$var3);
$fp = fopen('myFile.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($tempArr));
fclose($fp);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code works fine for me. I think the variable values are relevant here.

Comment: I'd begin by looking what is in $var1, $var2, and $var3. Try replacing one a time until you know which one is the problem, then print_r the contents of that variable and post here

Answer (score 1):

Your error probably boils down to:

```
$a = array(&$a);
json_encode($a);
```

See: http://codepad.org/8dYy8Y3C

so you have a reference cycle somewhere in $var1, $var2, or $var3. Your mission: search and destroy it! As Jamie Bicknell commented: remove one at a time to see which one.